# Which configuration for a real time API in a production environment?

Tags: django, rest, real-time

I will start an application which needs to be real time. I am looking for develop a real time REST Api, after research I am a little bit confused about the best configuration to do so, especially in a production environment.

Do you think that Django + Redis can be the best possible stack ?

Comment: what do you call a "realtime api" ?

Comment: I need to have a kind of mix between a REST api and websockets. I want that all my clients or group of clients be notified when a modification occured.

Answer (score 0):

For the API you can use [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

For the realtime part you can use [gevent-socketio](http://gevent-socketio)

Here you can find an example on how to implement a chat with [django and gevent-socketio](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/tree/master/examples/django_chat)

Comment: Thank you for  your reply, have you ever test this stack on production ?

Comment: I have tested django rest framework which is really great. But I have never tested gevent-socketio. Considering the 856 stars it has I assume it is great. Another possibility would have to set a socket-io server, but I assume that you prefer python !